# adding text field from PostgreSQL table without geometry

Tags: postgresql, postgis, qgis

I would like to add a variable text to the qgis graph,  where data is in a postgres **table without geometries**.

it's the timestamp of the currently used dataset.

Query should be

```
select timestamp from timestamps where tablename='collected_admin_boundaries';
```

which will return a timestamp like "2019-02-27 23:00:03+01"

this value should be visible on the graph in a extra box.

any ideas?

```
 \d timestamps
                              Tabelle »public.timestamps«
   Spalte   |             Typ             | Sortierfolge | NULL erlaubt? | Vorgabewert 
------------+-----------------------------+--------------+---------------+-------------
 tablename  | text                        |              |               | 
 timestamp  | timestamp with time zone    |              |               | 
 created_at | timestamp without time zone |              |               | 

select * from timestamps;
               tablename                |       timestamp        |         created_at         
----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------------
 collected_city_boundaries              | 2016-11-06 19:45:02+01 | 2016-11-07 12:28:34.28084
 collected_addrs                        | 2016-11-09 14:42:02+01 | 2016-11-10 00:21:06.898972
 collected_admin_boundaries_test_before | 2018-12-21 23:04:02+01 | 2018-12-22 01:58:59.354357
 collected_admin_boundaries_test        | 2018-12-22 16:03:02+01 | 2018-12-22 17:04:31.364394
 collected_postcode_boundaries          | 2019-03-01 03:58:02+01 | 2019-03-01 05:00:01.734494
 collected_postcodes                    | 2019-03-01 04:25:02+01 | 2019-03-01 05:26:41.522536
 collected_admin_boundaries_before      | 2019-02-27 23:00:03+01 | 2019-02-28 00:01:53.311602
 collected_admin_boundaries             | 2019-03-01 03:18:02+01 | 2019-03-01 04:19:26.64088
 countries2                             | 2019-03-01 03:18:02+01 | 2019-03-01 10:33:27.279113
(9 Zeilen)
```

Comment: Do you have a schema or any example queries you are running?

Comment: added infos. query is already listed.

Comment: this is what i need: https://wambachers-osm.website/images/osm/snaps_2019/missing_boundaries_20190301.png - added text by hand